# Error when I try to access to a class struct

Tags: c++

I am trying to access to a class struct but it gives me the following error:

**InternalGpsReceiver.h:**

```
class InternalGpsReceiver {
    public:
        static struct gps_data_t gpsdata;
        InternalGpsReceiver(void);
};
```

**InternalGpsReceiver.cpp:**

```
InternalGpsReceiver::InternalGpsReceiver(void){
    int err = gps_open("localhost", DEFAULT_GPSD_PORT, this->&gpsdata);
}
```

**Compilation error:**

> ```
> error: expected unqualified-id before '&' token 
>     int err = gps_open("localhost", DEFAULT_GPSD_PORT, this->&gpsdata);
> ```

Comment: Looks like you need `&InternalGpsReceiver::gpsdata` there.

Comment: When I try this I obtain the following error: undefined reference to `InternalGpsReceiver::gpsdata'

Comment: Don't you just need `int err = gps_open("localhost", DEFAULT_GPSD_PORT, gpsdata);` or do you need to pass a pointer: `int err = gps_open("localhost", DEFAULT_GPSD_PORT, &gpsdata);`?

Comment: How is `gps_open()` defined?

Comment: @ClaudiaGR Besides the declaration you'll need to add a definiton for your static class member variable outside of the class declaration. In your `.cpp` file add `gps_data_t InternalGpsReceiver::gpsdata;`.

Comment: @EdChum I need to pass a pointer.

Comment: When `gpsdata` is `static`, the `this->` is meaningless as the variable is common to *all* objects of the type.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize your struct before using it. Check http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static for a complete explanation.

Below is a minimal code that compiles. I just created a mockups for gps_data_t, gpsopen and DEFAULT_GPSD_PORT.

**InternalGpsReceiver.h:**

```
#define DEFAULT_GPSD_PORT 8080

struct gps_data_t {
    int a;
    int b;
};

int gps_open(const char *xx, int x, struct gps_data_t *gps){ return 1;}

class InternalGpsReceiver {
public:
    InternalGpsReceiver(void);
    static gps_data_t gpsdata;
}
```

**InternalGpsReceiver.cpp:**

```
#include "InternalGpsReceiver.h"

// The line that you missed.
gps_data_t InternalGpsReceiver::gpsdata;

InternalGpsReceiver::InternalGpsReceiver(void)
{
    int err = gps_open("localhost", DEFAULT_GPSD_PORT, &InternalGpsReceiver::gpsdata);
};


int main()
{
    InternalGpsReceiver x = InternalGpsReceiver();
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: The struct is initialize in an internal library. The problem was that I forgot to put "gps_data_t InternalGpsReceiver::gpsdata;" in my .cpp. Thank you so much for your answer.